# change the cell colour in one worksheet based on the cell colour in another worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have not used VBA before and want to change the cell colours in one sheet (Worksheet 2 A3:A600) based on the colour of the cells in another sheet (worksheet 1 A3:A600) but haven't got a clue where to start

Comment: Is the colour applied manually or with conditional formatting?

Comment: `For Each c in Sheet1.Range("A3:A600").Cells: Sheet2.Cells(c.row, c.column).interior.color = c.interior.color: Next c`

Answer (score 0):

I think that

```
sheets(2).range("A3:A600").Interior.Color 
  = sheets(1).range("A3").Interior.Color
```

should do what you're looking for